# How to modify the object that passes a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm kind of new in JS and jQuery, and this is my first question here, I hope I make it clear:

I have a list of `<a>`, and I want to apply style only to the one whose `href` is the same than the URL.

I tried to simplify my html to show you, something like this:

```
<a href="/myWeb/001.html"></a>
<a href="/myWeb/002.html"></a>
<a href="/myWeb/003.html"></a>
<a href="/myWeb/004.html"></a>
```

Then, this is what I started on my Script (with jQuery):

```
var url = window.location.pathname;

if($('a').attr('href') === url){

  //and now I want to apply .css() only to the <a> that passes the condition

}
```

So, is frustrating I can't achieve to attack the right object, and I guess is more than simple :/, any tip?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the `:active` CSS attribute modifier?

Comment: Use `.each()` to iterate over your `a` tags and later use `$(this)` to target that specific element.

Comment: `$("a[href='"+url+"']")` will safely select only the `a` you want.

Comment: Remember to pick the answer that solved your problem best by clicking the checkmark left of it. Any helpful answer should also be upvoted by clicking the upward arrow left of that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The force is with you if you have CSS powers.

Simply select only that `a`:

```
$("a[href="+url+"]")
```

This is done using the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) from CSS.

Then go ahead an do your `.css()` magic:

```
$("a[href="+url+"]").css(/*whatever you desire*/);
```

This will work for relative URLs like those you showed in your code.

To make it also safe for URLs like `//code.google.com/whatever/abc.html` you need to pass URL enclosed in single quotes:

```
$("a[href='"+url+"']")
```

Comment: The actual value of `url` may interfere with the comparison

Comment: According to the relative URLs OP showed in their code, this will work as-is.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery's [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
var url = "/myWeb/004.html";

$("a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("href") === url;
}).css("background-color", "red");
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgtq06mf/1/).

Comment: Why use a filter function when you can just make use of advanced CSS selectors here?

Comment: I agree, your alternative is better. This should be used just in the case the comparison is not trivial (which is not the case here)

Comment: Yeah, it it weren't that trivial, a `filter` function would be the best approach. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: For a beginner in Javascript/jQuery it might be very helpful to explain what a `filter()` function actually does and how it works (even if you only copy the relevant parts from MDN or jQuery docs).

Comment: sure, I'm checking the `.filter()` option as well, it will be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;

$('a[href]').filter(function() { return this.href === url; } ).css({
   ...
});
```

Comment: Why use a filter function when you can just make use of advanced CSS selectors here?

Comment: @connexo, Eventually, you'll need a fine grained control over the actual comparison.

Comment: In that case, yes. In this case, no. *Premature optimization is the source of all evil.* Arguments starting with "eventually" should raise your suspicion :D

Comment: It might be worth explaining why it works to access the native DOM node property `href` on `this` inside the filter function even though you iterate over a collection of jQuery objects.